# Is the J2SE com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter still the standard way to write barcodes?

Tags: eclipse, zxing

I notice that there are a lot of old tutorials from about 2010 that use

```
com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter
```

to write 2D barcodes to files.

Also, I notice a lot of old tutorials specify the use of Android.

I am using Eclipse on Linux Mint, not Android.

Eclipse will happily import the main src tree of java files and show them as available packages.  For example, I can get all the packages under zxing/core/src/main/java to show up; I can import classes from those packages and compile them.

However, I can't seem to import the com.google.zxing.client.j2se package when I have the core packages imported, and vice versa.

If there is a way to write BitMatrix objects to files without using

```
com.google.zxing.client.j2se
```

that would simplify matters.

Alternatively, if there is some way to get Eclipse to import both sets of packages, that might be an alternative.  I have already tried modifying the "filters" under the "properties" tab, on the theory that if I can use two filters, the first can pick up

core/src/main/java

and the second can pick up

/javase/src/main/java/

But that didn't work for me.

Suggestions are welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into the same problem with the import. It appears that we both forgot to add the javase.jar into the project. Download it from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/zxing/javase/3.1.1-SNAPSHOT/), import and you will be able to import MatrixToImageWriter.

Comment: Thank you.  I had not even realized that I needed another jar.  I assume this "javase" jar is a bunch of utilities needed to make zxing work with Java SE, and not part of the standard Java SE distribution.