# package com.google.zxing.client.j2se does not exist bufferedimageluminancesource

Tags: java, zxing

I am trying to use the zxing library to ready qr codes but one of the packages seems to be missing.

I keep getting this error:

> package com.google.zxing.client.j2se does not exist

This is the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Has anyone encountered this and knows how to fix the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the J2SE com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter still the standard way to write barcodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054607/is-the-j2se-com-google-zxing-client-j2se-matrixtoimagewriter-still-the-standard)

Comment: To be specific, you need to add a dependency to [`com.google.zxing:javase`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase)